# How to get the summay text after the jenkins pipeline job complete

Tags: jenkins

In my one jenkins pipeline job, I use `createSummary` of [post build plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Groovy+Postbuild+Plugin) to add some log url on the jenkins job UI. For the files moved to somewhere else, so I want to change the url. Is there a way to reset the information for this build?

```
manager.createSummary("red/yellow/green.gif")
  .appendText("""<a href=\"${url}\">log</a>""", false, false, false, "black")
```

Any tips/advice are appriciated, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

I finally solved it using BadgeSummaryAction.

```
 Jenkins.instance.getItemByFullName(jobName).builds.findAll { it.number > startnumber && 
 it.number < endnumber}.each { 
        List<Action> actions = it.getActions();
        List<BadgeSummaryAction> summaryActions = it.getActions(BadgeSummaryAction.class);
        String iconText = "green.gif"
        for(int i =0; i<summaryActions.size();i++) {
            BadgeSummaryAction currentAction = summaryActions.get(i);
            String sActionText = currentAction.getText()
            if(sActionText.contains("FAILED")){
                iconText = "red.gif"
            }else if(sActionText.contains("UNSTABLE")){
                iconText = "yellow.gif"
            }
            actions.remove(currentAction);
            BadgeSummaryAction summary = new BadgeSummaryAction(iconText)
            summary.appendText(replaceText, false);
            it.addAction(summary);

        }//end of for
}
```